# Redefining Commands Using DeclareRobustCommand

Tags: macros, robust-commands

I am trying to create the following commands. I want to replace `\exp` by a command that takes an input and outputs `\exp(#1)`. Trying to copy something that I was shown before, I tried the following

```
\let\EXP\relax
\DeclareRobustCommand{\EXP}{\exp}
\rewnewcommand{\exp}[1]{\EXP(#1)}
```

However, upon compiling, I get a `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry` error. If I don't redefine `exp`, but call it something like `expm`, then there are no issues. I'd prefer to redefine it though. How can I get around this?

Comment: This cannot work: TeX will chase its tail trying to substitute `\exp` with `\exp`.

Comment: What should `\EXP(1)` give you?

Comment: Yes, so I have discovered. How can I get around this? I don't know the code for the \exp function (I know it has automatic spacing, but I don't know what)

Comment: @Manuel `\EXP(1)` is (/should be) just the same as what `\exp(1)` would normally do

Comment: `\DeclareRobustCommand{\EXP}[1]{\exp(#1)}`

Comment: Yeah, I realise, but I wanted to type `\exp` each time not `\EXP` -- just generally easier, and more natural with the rest of my macros, but if that's all that's possible...

Comment: `\let\originalexp\exp \let\exp\relax \DeclareRobustCommand\exp[1]{\originalexp(#1)}`

Comment: Yep, that works. It's almost exactly the same as mine, but I did `Declare...` the other way around, and didn't do `\let\exp\relax`. If you make that into an answer, I'll accept it. (egreg's answer is very interesting and illuminating, but yours is precisely what I was looking for.)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't do this: I see no advantage in typing `\exp{3}` over `\exp(3)`, *unless* you want to do something more, that is, adding the possibility of sizing the parentheses.

This can be done with `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\paren}{(}{)}
\let\originalexp\exp

\renewcommand\exp{\originalexp\paren}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\exp{x}\quad\exp[\big]{x}\quad\exp*{\frac{\pi}{2}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I'd avoid this and rather define `\expp`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\paren}{(}{)}
\newcommand\expp{\exp\paren}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\expp{x}\quad\expp[\big]{x}\quad\expp*{\frac{\pi}{2}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

What's going wrong with your definition?

Upon calling `\exp{1}`, TeX will do `\EXP(1)`, which becomes `\exp(()1)` which becomes `\EXP(()1)`, which becomes `\exp(()()(1)`…

Comment: What I was doing further was defining `\expb` to be with `big` brackets, `\expB` with `Big`, `\expbb` with `bigg` and `\expBB` with `Bigg`. Using `\paren` is interesting though. I don't, however, see the benefit of typing `\expp[\big]{x}` every time when I can just type `\expb{x}`...

Comment: @SamT You can add `\newcommand{\expb}{\expp[\big]}` if you so prefer.

Comment: Yeah, very true. Is that then any more beneficial than Manuel's suggestion? (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398175/redefining-commands-using-declarerobustcommand#comment990507_398175)

Comment: @egreg `\exp{1}`, `\EXP(1)`, `\exp(1)`, `\EXP(()1)`, `\exp(()1)`, `\EXP(()()1)`, etc.